# Using ffmpeg to download m3u8 video in two ways resulting in two vastly different sizes; Why?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, mp4

I'm trying to download a m3u8 playlist (which contains 1.ts, 2.ts,..., xxx.ts) via ffmpeg. I'm doing it in two different ways:

- Directly download:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://filelocation/chunked/myfile.m3u8" -codec copy filename_v1.mp4
```

- download all .ts chunks to local; create a .txt file listing all the .ts files; combine into one .ts file; convert to .mp4 file:

```
for i in {1..xxx}; do curl "https://filelocation/chunked/$i.ts" -o "$i.ts"; done;
```

```
for i in `\ls *.ts | sort -V`; do echo "file '$i'"; done >> list.txt
```

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy filename_v2.ts
```

```
ffmpeg -i filename_v2.ts filename_v2.mp4
```

The two mp4 files I ended up with are vastly different in size, filename_v2.mp4 is about 1/10 the size of filename_v1.mp4 (say each chunk is ~5MB and I have 100 of them, filename_v1.mp4 would be ~500MB while filename_v2.mp4 would be ~50MB); also filename_v2.mp4 would be slightly shorter than filename_v1.mp4 in duration. Why is this? Is one the the method "wrong"?

Answer (score 1):

The command `ffmpeg -i filename_v2.ts filename_v2.mp4` recompresses the media. It's no longer the source data.

Instead, when generating list.txt, drop the `file` and use `echo "$i"` and then run,

`ffmpeg -f mpegts -i concatf:list.txt -c copy filename_v2.mp4`